# Process start from two strings

Tags: c#, winforms, process.start

I am trying to open a file which a user can set. In other words it will never be a set path or file. so when the user has selected the file they want to open this button below will open it. I have declared l1 and p1 as public strings.

```
    public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
         if (result == DialogResult.OK)
         {

             l1 = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
             p1 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

         }


    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //p1 = directory path for example "C:\\documents and settings\documents"
    //l1 = filename

        Process.Start(p1+l1);
    }
```

So just to review I want to open up the file just using the directory path and filename. Is this possible? I can just have p1 there and it will open an explorer showing me that directory. Thank you for looking.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? If not, what was the error?

Comment: So what problems are you having?  Have you tried this code? Does it work, are there problems with it? Are you simply concerned about design or security types of issues?

Comment: Sorry I should of been more specific the error states "The system cannot find the file specified." I keep finding other peoples code on the net when they know the set path and the program they want to access. I want it to be more dynamic than that. However Havn't found anyone that wants to do what I am doing - Which I find odd.

Comment: Never just concatenate paths, always look for a better way, e.g. [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will work, but I would recommend you update your code this instead:

```
var path = Path.Combine(p1, l1);
Process.Start(path);
```

Comment: This works as I have just tested it in a textbox however it will not load the file. I have a feeling it's something to do with spaces in the filename and the .doc extension has been taken off. So still having the same error.

Comment: Strange the `Path.GetFileName` should not remove the extension.  Neither should the spaces be an issue.

Comment: Just tested the code on my machine. Opened a Word doc from my desktop and it worked as expected.  The path also contained spaces.

Comment: Thank you it was my error in the end a bit of code I took out stopped it from working properly. Thank you for your help - What a releif was ready to tear my hair out.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use string concatenation to combine a directory and filename. In your case the  resulting string will look like this:

```
C:\documents and settings\documentsfilename
                                  ^^
                             this is wrong
```

Instead use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).

```
string path = Path.Combine(p1, l1);
Process.Start(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply do this: -

```
public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileNameWithPath;
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileNameWithPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(fileNameWithPath);
}
```